# PiCamera - how do I save an 'rgb' formatted np.arrray capture to a file?

Tags: python, image, raspberry-pi, rgb

```
import time
import picamera
import picamera.array
import numpy as np

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (100,100)
    time.sleep(2)
    image = np.empty((128,112, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    camera.capture(image, 'rgb')
    image = image[:100, :100]
```

My question is - how do I get that 'image' saved as a .png file? I am hoping to capture images for a machine learning project.

The result of `help(camera.capture) is below:

capture(output, format=None, use_video_port=False, resize=None, splitter_port=0, bayer=False, **options) method of picamera.camera.PiCamera instance
    Capture an image from the camera, storing it in *output*.

```
If *output* is a string, it will be treated as a filename for a new
file which the image will be written to. If *output* is not a string,
but is an object with a ``write`` method, it is assumed to be a
file-like object and the image data is appended to it (the
implementation only assumes the object has a ``write`` method - no
other methods are required but ``flush`` will be called at the end of
capture if it is present). If *output* is not a string, and has no
``write`` method it is assumed to be a writeable object implementing
the buffer protocol. In this case, the image data will be written
directly to the underlying buffer (which must be large enough to accept
the image data).
```

It seems to me that the 'image' is going into an underlying buffer (which I know nothing about). How do I capture that buffer to a file? Am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **PIL**, or other library to convert the Numpy array to a `PIL Image` and save it...

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.fromarray(YourNumpyImage)
im.save(’result.png’)
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that earlier and while it does save an image, the image is not one that is recognizable. So perhaps my issue is not with the saving of the image, but with the way my image is being created or captured.

Comment: Maybe try printing your Numpy array’s `shape` and `dtype` and comparing that to the dimensions of the PNG you get... also print your `image.max()`

Comment: How did you get on? Any luck?

Comment: thank you for the reply. I got pulled into a work crisis maelstrom and have not been able to get back to this to test it out. Planning to get back to it over the holidays.